# Using Space Mouse Pro on Google Virtual Machine

Tags: properties, 3d-mouse

I'm trying to set up my Space Mouse Pro to work with my nvidia-gaming-windows-server-2019-4-vm on Google Cloud. I have managed to connect it using USB Network Gate and it is detected by Windows Server, however not by Blender.
In device manager it appears as 3D connexion Space mouse pro. In the general tab of the properties window under Location, it figures under Location 0 instead of a COM port.
I'm not sure if Blender scans from COM ports when initializing and maybe that is why it's not finding it.
Any thoughts what I could try?

Comment: A COM port? How old is your computer?

Comment: Hi Lukasz, 
Even though they’ve fallen out of use, all connections by either USB or FireWire are termed COM ports as the designation still applies. Since there are many kinds of peripherals one can attach to a computer, COM port assignation is carried out by software and, because the COM port is virtual and not hardware, the assignation of COM port numbers can extend for any number of digits (COM255 for example).
Programs that manage microcontrollers however, usually search for these peripherals between COM1 and COM8 (the original allotment for hardware serial ports for PCs).

Comment: If you connect a microcontroller to a PC via a serial‐to‐USB interface, the computer will assign it the next available virtual COM port which, as stated before, can be well above COM8. Given this, the program that manages said device will be unable to find it unless you manually reassign the COM port numbers.